# Anagram project

Tags: c, function, anagram

I am having trouble trying to get the "isZero" function to detect if the word is an anagram or not. Asking if "isZero" is equal to 1 in main() it will only give me "anagram". And if i set it to 0 it will only give me "not anagram". To me it is not computing anything, it is just printing out whatever statement is true at the moment. Not sure how to solve this and could use some guidance.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <ctype.h>

 #define MAX 26

void intialize(char a[], char b[], int c[]);
void setLetters(char newCount[], int newNumber[]);
void checkLetters(char b[], int newNumber[]);
int isZero(int c[]);
void getstring(char a[]);
void getString(char b[]);

int main(void)
{
    char a[MAX], b[MAX];
    int c[MAX];

    intialize( a, b, c);
    getstring(a);
    getString(b);
    setLetters(a, c);
    checkLetters(b, c);

    if (isZero(c) == 1) {
        printf("anagram");
    } else
        printf("not anagram");
    return 0;
}

void intialize(char a[], char b[], int c[])
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < MAX; ++i) {

        a[i] = '\0';
        b[i] = '\0';
        c[i] = 0;
    }
}
void setLetters(char newCount[], int newNumber[])
{
    int i, index = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < MAX; ++i) {
        if(isalpha(newCount[i])) {
            newCount[i] = tolower(newCount[i]);
            index = (int)(newCount[i] - 'a');
            newNumber[index] +=1;
        }
    }
}
void checkLetters(char b[], int newNumber[])
{
    int i, index;
    for(i = 0; i < MAX; ++i) {
        if(isalpha(newNumber[i])) {
            newNumber[i] = tolower(newNumber[i]);
            index = (int)(newNumber[i] - 'a');
            newNumber[index] -= 1;
        }
    }
}
int isZero(int c[])
{
    int i, j = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < MAX; ++i) {
        if(c[i] == 0)
            j = 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
    return j;
}
void getstring(char a[])
{
    char line[MAX];

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    gets(line);
}
void getString(char b[])
{
    char line[MAX];

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    gets(line);
}
```

Comment: Instead of `initialize`, you know you can simply declare `char a[MAX] = {0};` and `int c[MAX] = {0};` (same for `b`). Also **never, never, never** use **gets()!**. It is **No Longer** part of the C library due to insecurity. Use `fgets`, `getline` or even `scanf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With C it is mandatory that you slow down and understand what each part of each line does. There is no part of C where **close enough** is **correct**. That being said, you had an overall idea about how to approach the problem. However, it was very clear that you are just starting out in C (given the other answers and comments).

Before you start writing functions, determine what you need a function to do. Then try and determine how best to handle that task. If you need a function to get string input, then write one to do that. If you find yourself having to write one function to fill each string **stop**, your have just defeated the purpose of the function. Writing a function to do the same thing for `a[]` and another **identical function** for `b[]` makes no sense. You don't need a function to loop through all arrays setting your newly declared arrays to `zero/NULL`, that's what array initialization syntax is for.

Before you expect to have functions work, take the time to learn how to pass values to (and if a return is needed -- get values from) a function. When you pass an array to a function, **pointer decay** occurs. That means array `a[]` decays to `*a` when passed to a function. You can take advantage of this by declaring your functions to accept `*a` as the argument. While this isn't earth-shattering for a simple `1-D` array, the decay becomes more involved with `2-D` arrays and above.

In addition to figuring out which code makes sense as a function, you need to be just as exact with your logic in C as you are with its syntax. If there is any part of a line your are unsure about, look it up, look at the man page for the function you are using, or consult a language reference for your compiler (Gnu/MS), etc. to make sure you know exactly what your code does. It will save you time in the long run. The number one thing that trips new C programmers up, is trying to **skim the manual** or **skim the book** and then start writing code. The key to learning C is to just **slow down**.

**Never, Never, Never use `gets()`**. If you are taking a class and the teacher hands you an assignment using it, go to administration and ask for a refund. `gets()` is no longer part of the standard C library due to how easily it is compromised and exploited. Use `fgets`, `getline`, or `scanf` (read the entire section on proper use of the `scanf` **format string** if you chose to use it). It is a fine function, but it has many, many pitfalls just waiting for someone that partially understands its use.

That being said, you had the overall logic for one approach to anagrams. Below I've provided an example of the points above in sorting out your code. Take the time to read through it and understand why I made the changes I did. Additionally, I added a quick `length` check for the words input. If they are not the same length, no need to go further. Let me know if you have questions. There are a lot of good folks here that are happy to help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 26

void setLetters(char *newCount, int *newNumber);
void checkLetters(char *newCount, int *newNumber);
int isZero (int *c);
void getstring (char *a);

int main (void)
{
    char a[MAX] = {0};  /* initialize all to zero/NULL */
    char b[MAX] = {0};
    int  c[MAX] = {0};

    getstring(a);
    getstring(b);
    printf ("\n You entered:\n\n  a: %s\n  b: %s\n\n", a, b);

    /* test lengths - if differ, not anagram */
    if (strlen(a) != strlen(b)) {
        printf (" Lenghts differ, cannot be an anagram.\n\n");
        return 1;
    }

    setLetters (a, c);      /* set key array  (c)   */
    checkLetters (b, c);    /* check key array (c)  */

    if (isZero(c))
        printf(" The words form an anagram.\n\n");
    else
        printf(" The words are not and anagram.\n\n");

    return 0;
}

void setLetters (char *newCount, int *newNumber)
{
    int i = 0;
    int index = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX; ++i) {
        if (isalpha (newCount[i])) {
            newCount[i] = tolower (newCount[i]);
            index = (int)(newCount[i] - 'a');
            newNumber[index] +=1;
        }
    }
}

void checkLetters(char *newCount, int *newNumber)
{
    int i = 0;
    int index = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX; ++i) {
        if (isalpha (newCount[i])) {
            newCount[i] = tolower (newCount[i]);
            index = (int)(newCount[i] - 'a');
            newNumber[index] -= 1;
        }
    }
}

int isZero (int *c)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX; ++i)
        if (c[i] == 1)
            return 0;

    return 1;
}

void getstring (char *a)
{
    printf ("\n Enter a string: ");
    scanf  ("%[^\n]%*c", a);
}
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/anaproj

 Enter a string: yekcim

 Enter a string: mickey

 You entered:

  a: yekcim
  b: mickey

 The words form an anagram.

$ ./bin/anaproj

 Enter a string: yekcim

 Enter a string: mickez

 You entered:

  a: yekcim
  b: mickez

 The words are not and anagram.
```

Comment: Thank you very much. There are several questions I would like to ask about your code, there are simply certain things you implemented or changed which I do not understand. As of now it is very late and need to go to sleep. But I will be sure to come back to this discussion. Thanks again.

Comment: Sure. Drop a comment, If I'm on, I'll be happy to open a chat window with you.

Answer (score 1):

```
void getstring(char a[]);
```

This API is not doing what you intend to do.
This has a local variable line and your are reading a string to it and the char array in `main()` i.e. `a` is never been filled up with anything.

You continue to use the char array `a` thinking the values are filled in it by calling getstring() which is not happening. You need to fix this first and later work on the algorithm for anagram.
There is something called pass by reference which might help you.